# webdriver bean launches browser every time if you decleare in context.xml with spring test framework

Tags: spring, automation, webdriver, testng

I have a simple question regarding Webdriver and Spring test Framework. I have declared a bean in my context.xml as follows:

```
<bean id="driver" class="org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver" />
```

I created a BaseScript class where i injected firefox bean using @autowired method as follows:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:/applicationContext.xml")

public abstract class TestScriptBase extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{

@Autowired
private WebDriver driver ;
```

Now i created my signin Script as follows:

```
public class SigninTest extends TestScriptBase{

@Test
public void testSignin(){
    System.out.println("Testing..");
}
```

}

Now my Question is:
Is this the right way of initialize webdriver? If so then when i add driver.quit() at @afterClass in my TestScriptBase class then  next script does not execute due to  driver session gets null. If i add scope="prototype" in the bean definition then multiple browser opens because each pageClass new driver is being initiated.

Please Help....

Thanks